# Vbscript - The OpenTextFile Not Working in Azure

Tags: azure, vbscript, asp-classic

We have in Azure a **Classic ASP** app. It was working smoothly for years. But since yesterday a `OpenTextFile` code is not working.

This is our code:

```
set fs     = server.CreateObject ( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
set fFile = fs.OpenTextFile ( filePath, 1, true )
```

The last parameter in `fs.OpenTextFile`, `true`, tells: [create the file if it doesn't exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/opentextfile-method).

But suddently since yesterday it is not working.

We tested locally our app and that code is working. It creates the file if it doesn't exists. But since yesterday in Azure it doesn't works.

Any from Azure that help us?

Comment: How are we suppose to help, we don’t know your environment other than it’s running on Azure, what about the specific error you receive? Are we just expected to guess?

Comment: Sorry @Lankymar, I was thinking that any of Azure team read it and know about any issues and changes in Scripting Azure objets.

Comment: This isn't using Azure objects, it's using Classic ASP with VBScript which will behave the same wherever it is run from. What won't be the same is how it is handled by IIS / Azure instances in relation to authorization/privileges etc.

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart . That's what we were thinking. We are so strange why this Classical ASP/VBScript is not working anymore after years and without code or environment changes. That was very strange. :(

Answer (score 0):

We fixed our problem using `FileExists` method:

```
if Not fs.FileExists(filePath) then
   set tfile = fs.CreateTextFile(filePath)
   tfile.close
end if
```

But what strange that the method `OpenTextFile` don't create the file if if don't exists anymore.

Comment: Are there any other processes or scripts running which touch that file? Maybe something external changed?

Comment: Nope... There is no one.. And this unique process touch or create several different files every day.